# How can I handle exceptions that Process.run throws

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, exception, process

According to the available API and [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/2890105-run) `Process.run` method may throw exceptions. I'd like to handle the potential exceptions, but I can't find any documentation on what these exception can be.

How can I find relevant documentation and handle `Process.run` exceptions?

Example code:

```
func runProcess(process: Process) {
    do {
        try process.run()
    } catch ??? {
        // I don't know what exceptions can I catch here
    } catch {
        // If I use catch-all case, then the `error` object contains only
        // `localizedDescription` which doesn't help in handling errors either
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually bridged from `[NSTask - (BOOL)launchAndReturnError:(out NSError **_Nullable)error]`, so the thrown exception is NSError, so you can start from

```
func runProcess(process: Process) {
    do {
        try process.run()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // process NSError.code (domain, etc)
    } catch {
       // do anything else
    }
}
```

If it is interested specific code it might be handled via `CocoaError` (there are a lot of declared constants there)

> ```
> /// Describes errors within the Cocoa error domain.
> public struct CocoaError {
> ```

```
do {
    try process.run()
} catch CocoaError.fileNoSuchFile {
    print("Error: no such file exists")
}
```

Here is related documentation:

[Handling Cocoa Errors in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/handling_cocoa_errors_in_swift)

[CocoaError constants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/cocoaerror)

Comment: The “do anything else” case in the first example is not needed, *every* `Error` is bridgeable to `NSError`.